# Strange path `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm, io.js

I’m having a weird issue with npm shrinkwrap that causes weird file paths to show up in the `from` field.

```
"yar": {
      "version": "3.0.3",
      "from": "../../../../var/folders/g6/1ls5zynn1176qkks242mjc440000gn/T/npm-11740-b6d8c215/git-cache-84ce586bbe7d/7b6a3819be47034a7a2d2d303e695eefa2bdff2c",
      "resolved": "git://github.com/micahlmartin/yar#7b6a3819be47034a7a2d2d303e695eefa2bdff2c”,
```

I’m not sue if it’s an actual problem or not but it seems really strange. I’ve seen it happen with other packages too. Most everything else seems to have a much more normal looking from path like this:

```
"autoprefixer-loader": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "from": "autoprefixer-loader@>=1.1.0 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/autoprefixer-loader/-/autoprefixer-loader-1.1.0.tgz”,
```

any ideas what might be causing this? I'm running `nvm` so I'm not sure whether or not that has anything to do with it.

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7121

Answer (score 0):

Based on the ticket https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7121

This bug was introduced in npm v2.1.4 and was fixed in npm v2.7.1